# Ajuda com XML no PhP

Tags: php, xml

Galera,tenho o seguinte XML:

```
<erros>
    <erro>
       <description>Nao localizado</description>
    </erro>
    <erro>
       <description>Nao especificado</description>
    </erro>
</erros>
```

E quero saber como pego os 2 erros juntos no php já que se eu colocar:
`$xml->erros->erro->description;` vai abrir só um erro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bem isso é simples imagine que cada bloco de dados é um "nó", ou seja cada vez que você repete seu bloco você terá uma posição que corresponde a uma matriz, sendo assim basta correr todas as posições que terá todos os dados.

Não sei se esta carregando o xml de um arquivo ou de uma string mas um exemplo conceitual bem simples seria:

```
<?php
// Seus dados em XML
$xml = '<erros>
 <erro>
  <description>Nao localizado</description>
 </erro>
 <erro>
  <description>Nao especificado</description>
 </erro>
</erros>';

// Carrega os "nos" do XML usando a função do PHP 
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);

// Cria uma variável onde ira juntar os resultados
$errors = "";

// Faz o loop com a leitura de todos blocos de erros
foreach ($xml->erro as $er) {
 // Concatena os errros
 $errors .= $er->description . "\r\n";
}

// Apresenta os erros na tela
echo $errors;
?>
```